# Firebase query delete specific value from database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data on my firebase:

```
transportation: {
"car" : {
    "bus" : {
      "toyota" : false,
      "bmw" : true
    },
    "suv" : {
      "honda" : false,
      "toyota" : true,
    }
  }
}
```

I want to delete all child that have "false" value data so that my data looks like this:

```
transportation: {
    "car" : {
        "bus" : {

          "bmw" : true
        },
        "suv" : {

          "toyota" : true,
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is code,

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('transportation/')
   ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
  data = snapshot.val();
        for (var i=0;i < Object.keys(data).length;i++){
            Object.keys(data)[i].forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              if(childSnapshot.val() == "false"){
                  childSnapshot.ref.remove();
                }
              });
        }
  }).catch(function(error) {alert("Data could not be deleted." + error);}););
```

Comment: I think this is wrong !. as `childSnapshot.val() == "false"` is not correect data path. `childSnapshot.val()` will give an object `car:{...` and can not compare with `false`. Even one level deep will give another object.

Comment: @HakanC thanks for comment..! i have update my code..!

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete record from fairbase with its value, bellow may work:

```
var dB = firebase.database()
dB.ref('transportation/car').once('value', snap={
     snap.forEach(s =>{
        var obj =s.val();
        var keys = s.key;
          for (var key in obj ) {
            if (!obj[key]) {
               // In order to delete:  set the path null
               dB.ref('transportation/car/' + keys + "/" + key).set(null);
            }   
          }

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete data with specific value which `false` in your case . We needs to fetch all data for a node and then map through the data using keys to delete the data with exact value of object with value `false`.

```
let transportationRef = firebase.database().ref().child('transportation/')
  transportationRef.child("car").once('value', s => {
    if (s.exists()) {
      // map through objects returned from transportationRef and map through the objects
      Object.keys(s.val()).map(k => {
          // deleting the node which contains `false` as value
          if(s.val()[k]=="false"){
            s.ref.remove()
          }
      })
    }
})
```